# Laravel 5 BookStack fresh install not loading any external files

Tags: php, css, laravel-5

I have just installed a fresh copy of bookstack on my Ubuntu server. (https://www.bookstackapp.com/)

After fiddling around for ages trying to sort permissions and database issues, whenever I visit a page, none of the CSS or JS files are being found

[image]

When i visit a .css file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it, I hadn't applied correct permissions to bootstrap/cache

Comment: If you add some details that would be helpful. thanks

Comment: "I hadn't applied correct permissions to bootstrap/cache"

Comment: What permission did you set to make it work and how thanks?

Comment: I have a question posted can you help with removing this issue thanks. I think it is also a permission problem but I could not find solution. thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69011239/why-am-i-getting-forbidden-message-on-accessing-books-path-and-404-on-accessi

Comment: @MindRoasterMir run these commands:

chown -R yourUser:www-data /var/www/laravel_project/public/storage

chown -R yourUser:www-data /var/www/laravel_project/public/bootstrap/cache

chmod -R 774 /var/www/laravel_project/public/bootstrap/cache

chmod -R 774 /var/www/laravel_project/public/storage

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using XAMPP and Windows 10. You can see it in my question. Thanks.

Comment: in my installation there is not folder called "storage" in /public/ folder. I dont think there is a different in installation process or folder structure officially.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the document root is incorrect. Check that your web server is pointing to /your_app_root/public, as everything is resolved through this point. Also, does that package need assets compiled perhaps using something like gulp or webpack?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I managed to fix it, I hadn't applied correct permissions to `bootstrap/cache`

Comment: @Ben could you post this as an answer and mark it as correct answer?