# Why am I getting "forbidden" message on accessing /books path and 404 on accessing any book on BookStack

Tags: php, documentation

I have setup bookstack on Xampp + Windows 10. I am accessing it directly with apache server.
When I try to acces "/books" url it show a blanck white page with "forbidden" written on it.

[image: forbidden image for bookstack]

I can create shelfs and books but when I try to open any created book it show a 404 Apache page like this.

[image: 404 page on book access]

How can I solve this problem ?
I have tried all official and unofficial solutions but nothing helped.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this porblem with the help of the creator of stackbooks by removing the "/books" names alias from the apache config files.

The bookstack.amuslim.org/books was not going to the bookstack /books but to the "/books" alias.